# FACEBOOK - c# UserID/feed GET post comments Picture URL

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed, facebook-graph-api-v2.1

I'm using c# sdk to get facebook wall content: Username/feed 
In response I recive all messages and activities on the user’s wall. In message or story data we can find a Picture attribute which is a URL address to picture.
In each message i have a list of coresponding comments, but I can't find the Picture URL in comments data.

How can I get the Picture URL which was added in a comment ?

The best solution for me would be to get all necessary data (including comment pictures) by asking only one GET(Username/feed) question to FACEBOOK API.
Please HELP ME !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ***attachment*** edge on ***comments*** node, so final query will appear like this:

```
[user_id]/feed?fields=[comma separated fields],comments{attachment,[comma separated fields]}
```

For each comment with attached pictures there will be **attachment.media.image** object with **src** field that is exactly what you're looking for.